# Quarkus: basic auth through web-service

Tags: basic-authentication, quarkus

From a quarkus application, I need to:

- receive a request with a basic auth header
- from the username / password, request an external endpoint to get the roles

As I understand it now, quarkus supports basic auth but only with some predefined identity providers (https://quarkus.io/guides/security#identity-providers).

I'd like to avoid the manual processing of the request header...

Is there any way to do it from quarkus?